# Theorem of class field theory in appendix of the book 'Cyclotomic fields' by Washington

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I came across the following theorem of class field theory in the appendix of the book 'Cyclotomic fields' by Washington. I could not find it in Milne, Cassels Frohlich, Neukirch or Artin Tate.

> **Theorem 14.** (a) If $K/k$ is abelian, then there is a closed subgroup $H$ with $D_k\subseteq H\subseteq C_k$, such that
> $$C_k/H\simeq\mathrm{Gal}(K/k).$$
> The prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified $\Longleftrightarrow k^\times U_\mathfrak{p}/k^\times\subseteq H$.
>
> (b) Given a closed subgroup $H$ with $D_k\subseteq H\subseteq C_k$ (equivalently, $C_k/H$ is totally disconnected), there is a unique abelian extension corresponding to $H$, as in (a).

Where can I find proof and discussion on this theorem?

Answer (score 2):

this is called the existence theorem and I think it is mentioned in both Milne book and Cassels Frohlich, possibly with a different language. but It is discussed in length in the Bonn lecture of Neukirch https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642354366. the part about the ramification comes from local class field theory and compatibility of local and global class field theory.

Comment: The complete argument seems to be in Artin Tate. But the argument seems rather long, is there a short and crisp exposition?

Comment: the proof is a little technical, but the main idea is that: 1) if $H'\in H$ and there is an associated abelian extension for $H'$ then there is an abelian extension associated to $H$ this is an easy consequence of reciprocity theorem2)then you have  to compute the norm subgroup of kummer extensions and show that every closed subgroup contain norm group of a Kummer subgroup. or course in function fields you have to do a little more work because kummer extensions are not enough

Comment: if you are familiar with basic properties of ideles then the proof in bonn lectures is less than two pages, and I think every step is basically the only sensible thing you can do if you want to follow strategy of my last comment